# Rails Add icon to f.submit in slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design, slim-lang

So I'm going around adding icons to most of my buttons, and was wondering how I go about that on my submit button?

It's pretty simple code, not sure to why it's not working for a submit but works on all my other buttons?

```
.actions.right-align
  = f.submit class: "btn waves-effect waves-light"
    i.material-icons.left
      | remove_red_eye
```

I'm using the slim template engine and material icons (which shouldn't really make a difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work with `submit` is because it doesn't take a block as a parameter. However `button` takes a block and you can therefore do what you wanted to do with your code.

[button method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/button)

```
button(value = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

[submit method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit)

```
submit(value=nil, options={})
```

Comment: This is a better solution than what I provided, because it adds the reasoning as to why submit won't work. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunatelly `button` builds `<button>` tag instead `<input>` . And even passing `value` atrribute will not send it in params (in `:commit` key, as `<input>` do). But this is relevant only if You want differentiate  more submit buttons going to same url.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, I just changed my f.submit to a f.button:

```
  = f.button class: "btn waves-effect waves-light"
      i.material-icons.left
        | remove_red_eye
      | name the button here
```